# Is it okay to loop functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, built-in

Is there any kind of built-in method that would iterate through the object parameters without loop. Like the array object has methods(forEach, sort, filter..). 
For example there's an array

```
var numbers = [3,342,23,22,124];
var max = 0;
for(var i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    if(numbers[i] > max){
        max = numbers[i];
    }
}
alert(max);
```

Instead of looping `sort()` method could be used

```
var numbers = [3,342,23,22,124];
numbers.sort(function(a,b){return b - a});
alert(numbers[0]);
```

Is there any method for regular objects `{}` in JavaScript, that would work the same way as `sort()`?

More generally is there any way to avoid such looping:

```
for(var parameter in object){
    var data = object[parameter]
    exampleMethod(data);
}
```

is there a way to execute a function several times without looping?

Comment: Objects keys are unsorted, so sorting is out of the question. The closest to looping is getting the keys and running an array method over those.

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can often use a function like `Object.keys()` to open a pathway to the Array prototype methods like `.forEach()`.

The `Object.keys()` method returns an array with the "own" property names of an object. (The "own" names are the names of properties directly on the object, and not inherited from the prototype chain.) From there, you can use the Array methods like `.forEach` to iterate through the property names and, by using those to reference the object, through the property values as well.

For example, consider this object:

```
var dimensions = {
  length: 20,
  height: 30,
  width: 40
};
```

If you wanted to sum up the edges, you could do this:

```
var perimeter = Object.keys(dimensions).reduce(function(sum, dkey) {
    sum += 4 * dimensions[dkey];
    return sum;
}, 0);
```

Note also the related methods `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` and `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`, which expand the properties available for iteration.

Comment: I was going to suggest lodash `pairs`. Your answer is better. Though old-IE (<9) does not support this ES5 feature. (although a polyfill is maybe better than something extra like lodash)

Comment: @BenMosher true, but MDN has a polyfill.

Comment: @imanEngineer No, theres no easy method to execute over each value of the object. Not without looping the keys and getting the values.

Comment: @RobG oh you're right; I was thinking of the methods that allow for `this` to be stipulated. Editing. (Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

Not like sort because there is no order of properties in JavaScript objects.  However, you can use Object.keys and map to turn an object into an array of values.

```
  var  o = {a:1,b:3, c, :2};
  var arr = Object.keys(o).map(key=>o[key]).sort((a,b)=>b-a);
  var max = arr[0];
```

For regular iteration, combine keys and forEach

```
Object.keys(o).forEach(key=>console.log('key',key, 'value', o[key]));
```